# Entering command correctly in visual mode

Tags: vim, macvim

I need to do a map for visual mode to apply some commands on the selection only. This implies that the `'<,'>` needs to appear in the command line.

As they appear automatically when you type `:`, I did the mappings without delimiters, something like `vmap ,{key} :{command}`. So far it's working, they are being shown as `:'<,'>{command}`.

But the question is, is it safe to rely on this behaviour? Or there is a better way to do a visual map and insert the delimiters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to rely on that behavior.  Vim always insert the visual range markers (`'<` and `'>`) when you press `:` while in visual mode.  Since a map is just a way to store a series of key presses (ignoring `<expr>` maps), it acts just like you had typed it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `<c-u>` at the start of your mapping to clear any range that might be there, and then add the range markers explicitly (`:<c-u>'<,'>`).

- `:help omap-info`
- `:help c_CTRL-U`

Comment: Thanks @bobbogo, nice to know about the <C-U> also! :)